# React: Algolia, algolia options search

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, algolia, docusaurus

I am struggling with configuring Algolia search, so that it returns only result for the current version. I have tried to include this into algolia config section; however, it does not return anything now. If I remove this code, the search bar suggests results from multiple versions. Do you guys/girls have any suggestions on how to get it working? Thank you

```js
 algoliaOptions: {
      facetFilters: ["version: VERSION"]
    },
```

Comment: Could you show what's inside your Algolia records? It would help to understand if filter is written correctly.

Comment: @SamuelVaillant Unfortunately I can't. I do not have the credentials to access Algolia records.

Comment: Your search is working without the filters correct? If yes you should be able to inspect the requests and look at the one made to Algolia. You'll have the shape of the records in the response of those requests.

Comment: @SamuelVaillant Update: it was solved by creating a PR request to docsearch config repo :). Thank you for the help though